# How to confirm if Gatling has actually loaded the web page

Tags: gatling

Pardon me for being so naive, but I am having pretty hard time to check/ confirm if my Gatling Script actually loads the page I want it to load, or not.
My Environment:
Windows 8.1 (64 - Bit)
Symantec Endpoint Protection
Scala: 2.11.4
Gatling: 2.0.3
Java: java version "1.7.0_72"
      Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_72-b14)
      64-Bit Server VM (build 24.72-b04, mixed mode)

I access my client's QA sites after making entries in my hosts file.

My script is as following:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.jdbc.Predef._

class ClientBe extends Simulation{
  val httpProtocol = http
        .baseURL("CLIENT URL")
        .inferHtmlResources(BlackList(""".*\.js""", """.*\.css""", """.*\.gif""", """.*\.jpeg""", """.*\.jpg""", """.*\.ico""", """.*\.woff""", """.*\.(t|o)tf""", """.*\.png"""), WhiteList())
        .acceptHeader("""image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5""")
        .acceptEncodingHeader("""gzip, deflate""")
        .acceptLanguageHeader("""en-US,en;q=0.5""")
        .connection("""keep-alive""")
        .contentTypeHeader("""application/ocsp-request""")
        .userAgentHeader("""Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0""")

   val headers_0 = Map("""Accept""" -> """text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8""")

    val headers_1 = Map("""Accept""" -> """*/*""")

    val headers_11 = Map(
        """Accept""" -> """*/*""",
        """If-Modified-Since""" -> """Thu, 27 Jan 2015 15:32:12 GMT""",
        """If-None-Match""" -> """W/"14228-1421335932000-gzip"""")

    val headers_14 = Map(
        """Accept""" -> """*/*""",
        """Cache-Control""" -> """no-cache""",
        """Pragma""" -> """no-cache""",
        """X-Requested-With""" -> """XMLHttpRequest""")

    val headers_17 = Map(
        """Accept""" -> """*/*""",
        """Cache-Control""" -> """no-cache""",
        """Content-Type""" -> """application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8""",
        """Pragma""" -> """no-cache""",
        """X-Requested-With""" -> """XMLHttpRequest""")

    val uri04 = """ CLIENT URL """

    val scn = scenario("Loading home page")
        // Loading QA2 Site (French)
        .exec(http("Loading QA2 Site Home Page")
            .get("""/?language=fr&cmpid=""")
            .headers(headers_0)
            .check(status.is(session => 200))
            .check(regex("""Identifiez-vous""").exists))
        .pause(1)       
        .exec(http("LoggingIn")
            .post("""/loginnotmandatory""")
            .headers(headers_0)
            .formParam("""j_username""","""my email id""")
            .formParam("""j_password""",""" password """)
            .check(status.is(session => 200))
            .check(regex("""Bienvenue""").exists))
            //.check(css("""a""").is("""Bienvenue""")))
         .pause(3)   
         .exec(http("Navigate to Promotions")
            .get("""/fr-be/promotions""")
            .headers(headers_0)
            .check(status.is(session => 200))
            .check(regex("""Top Promotions""").exists))
        .pause(2)

        .exec(http("Logging Out")
            .get("""/?logout""")
            .headers(headers_0)
            .check(status.is(session => 200))
            .check(currentLocation.is("""CLIENT URL/?logout"""))
            .check(regex("""Identifiez-vous""").exists))

    setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1))).protocols(httpProtocol)
}
```

The errors I get are something like this:
regex(Bienvenue).find(0).exists, found nothing
regex(Top Promotions).find(0).exists, found nothing

Any guidance will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

add a extraInfoExtractor to the httpProtocol to print the response

```
 .extraInfoExtractor {
      extraInfo =>
        extraInfo.status match {
          case io.gatling.core.result.message.KO =>
            {
              println("Request : " + extraInfo)
              println("Response Body : " + extraInfo.response.body.string)
            }
            Nil
          case io.gatling.core.result.message.OK =>

            Nil
          case _ => Nil
        }
    }
```